# Overflow: hidden errors

Tags: css, overflow

So on my website I have parts of the website that go off the screen, to fix this I used this css `* {overflow: hidden;}` or `body {overflow: hidden;}` but currently none of them are working and the scrollbars are there.

Comment: Please put up some code which shows the problem. As it stands there is not enough info for us to help.

Comment: Are you certain that the universal overflow: hidden isn't being overridden by some other CSS for some elements?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the parts themselves some css too, you could either try giving each of them one or multiple of the following css:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
float: left;
```

or you could also try putting them inside a div and styling the div too by attaching a class to the div `<div class="box"></div>` and then adding the `overflow:hidden;` to that new div instead of the website body itself

Answer (score 0):

You may have an overflowing element on the screen, check it.
If you still want to try;

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
```